# add php value in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

Ok this is the challenge i get. i have created a page of discipline in schools. whereby i get the title of victim, the name of the victim which hidden in the selection of the victim title using JavaScript. however i try calling php script in JavaScript, it fails. i need help. thanks in advance.

PHP CODE: 

                     Victim *

```
                         <?php 
                            $get_vic_type = "select * from user_roles";
                            $run_vic_type =  mysql_query($get_vic_type);
                            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($run_vic_type)) {
                                $vic_type_id = $row['id'];
                                $vic_type = $row['role'];
                                echo "<option value='$vic_type'>$vic_type</option>"; 
                                # code...
                            } 
                            ?>
                        <option value="student">Student</option>
                        <option value="visitor">Victim</option> 
                    </select>
                </td>
               </tr>
                <tr id="victim_name" style="display: none;">
                    <td align="right" style="width: 100%;">Victim Name : </td>
                    <td align="left" style="width: 100%;">
                    <select style="width: 100%;" name="vic_name" class="sect" placeholder="Victim's Name">
                        <?php 
                            $get_vic_name = "select * from  useraccounts";
                            $run_vic_name =  mysql_query($get_vic_name);
                            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($run_vic_name)) {
                                $v_name = $row['id'];
                                $vic_name = $row['name'];
                                echo "<option value='$vic_name'>$vic_name</option>"; 
                                # code...
                            } 
                            ?>
                    </select>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                <tr id="vis_name" style="display: none;">
                    <td align="right" style="width: 100%;">Visitor Name : </td>
                    <td align="left" style="width: 100%;"><input type="text" name="vic_name" placeholder="Visitor's Name"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="stud_name" style="display: none;">
                    <td align="right" style="width: 100%;">Student Name: </td>
                    <td align="left" style="width: 100%;"><select style="width: 100%;" class="sect" name="vic_name" placeholder="Student's Name" cols="9">
                        <option></option>
                        <?php 
                            $get_stud= "select * from studentdetails";
                            $run_stud =  mysql_query($get_stud);
                            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($run_stud)) {
                            $stud_id = $row['id'];
                            $stud_fname = $row['fname'];
                            $stud_lname = $row['lname'];
                            echo "<option value='$stud_fname $stud_lname'>". $stud_fname ." ". $stud_lname ."</option>"; 
                            # code...
                        } ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $("#victim").change(function (ev){
                if($(this).val()=='visitor') $("#vis_name").css("display", "table-row")
                else $("#vis_name").css("display", "none")

                if($(this).val()=='student') $("#stud_name").css("display", "table-row")
                    else $("#stud_name").css("display", "none")

                if($(this).val()==<?php echo $vic_type; ?>) $("#victim_name").css("display", "table-row")
                    else $("#victim_name").css("display", "none")
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. We wouldn't be able to help you with this :(

Answer (score 0):

Try `if($(this).val()==<?php echo $vic_type; ?>)`

Or , you can type the whole  tag inside php, something like : `<?php echo"//here_goes_your_script"; ?>` and you insert $vic_type with a simple concatenation

**EDIT :**

Here's a working code. the code layout should be like following :

```
    <?php 
        $get_vic_type = "select * from user_roles";
        $run_vic_type =  mysql_query($get_vic_type);
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $("#victim").change(function (ev){
            if($(this).val()=='<?php echo $vic_type; ?>')
                //your_(re)action;
            else 
                //your_(re)action;
          });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--your code-->
        <select id='victim'>
                <?php 
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($run_vic_type)) {
                       $vic_type_id = $row['id'];
                       $vic_type = $row['role'];
                       echo"<option value=".$vic_type.">".$vic_type."</option>"; 
                    }  
                 ?>
        </select>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The efficient way to do this is store value in hidden and then get values in javascript.

PHP:

```
 <select id="victim" name="vic_title" class="sect" plcaeholder="Select a Role">
 <?php 
 $get_vic_type = "select * from user_roles";
 $run_vic_type =  mysql_query($get_vic_type);
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($run_vic_type)) {
         $vic_type_id = $row['id'];
         $vic_type = $row['role'];
         echo "<option value='$vic_type'>$vic_type</option>"; 
                                # code...
     } 
?>
<option value="student">Student</option>
<option value="visitor">Victim</option> 
</select>
<input type='hidden' name='vic_type' id='vic_type' value='<?=$vic_type?>'>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
$("#victim").change(function (ev){
      if($(this).val()==$('#vic_type').val()) $("#victim_name").css("display", "table-row")
      else $("#victim_name").css("display", "none")
      });
</script>
```

Comment: thank you. However when i run the code it only  displays the $vic_type but i want it to display the hidden select option inside the $vic_type

Comment: $vic_type is the drop down value then what you are trying to store in hidden. @wizy Judah